# How to keep only certain df columns that appear as rows in another df

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

Assuming that we have two dataframes

`df_1`

```
+--------+--------+-------+-------+
| id     | col1   | col2  | col3  |
+--------+--------+-------+-------+
| A      |   10   |   5   |   4   |
| B      |   5    |   3   |   2   |
+--------+--------+-------+-------+
```

and `df_2`

```
+----------+--------+---------+
| col_name | col_t  | col_d   |
+----------+--------+---------+
| col1     |   3.3  |   2.2   |
| col3     |   1    |   2     |
+----------+--------+---------+
```

---

What I want to achieve is to join the two tables, such that only the columns that appear under `df_2`'s `col_name` are kept in `df_1` i.e. the desired table would be

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| id     | col1   | col3  |
+--------+--------+-------+
| A      |   10   |   4   |
| B      |   5    |   2   |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

**however, I need to perform this action only through joins and/or df transpose or pivot if possible.**

I know that the above could be easily inferred by just `select`ing the `df_1` columns as they appear in `df_2`'s `col_name` but this is not what I am looking for here

Comment: That sounds like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You're trying to mix data and metadata. That's not going to work well. Better present your complete business case so we can give you the best solution, not the one you imagine the best.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to dedup and obtain the values in `df_2.col_name` using `collect_list` and passing this list of column names in your `df_1` dataframe:

```
col_list = list(set(df_2.select(collect_list("col_name")).collect()[0][0]))
list_with_id = ['id'] + col_list

df_1[list_with_id].show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----+----+
| id|col1|col3|
+---+----+----+
|  A|  10|   4|
|  B|   5|   2|
+---+----+----+
```

Is this what you're looking for? (Assuming you want something dynamic and not manually selecting columns). I'm not using joins or pivots here though.